# Sorting Arrays. The first element is length of array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Question :
Sorted?) Write the following method that returns true if the list is already sorted in increasing order. public static boolean isSorted(int[] list) Write a test program that prompts the user to enter a list and displays whether the list is sorted or not. Here is a sample run. Note that the first number in the input indicates the number of the elements in the list.

My try:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem6_19 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number.  for the length of the list: ");
        int listLength = input.nextInt();
        int[] number = new int[listLength];

        for(int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
            number[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        if (isSorted(number)) {
            System.out.println("The list is sorted!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The list is NOT sorted!");
        }

    }

    public static boolean isSorted(int[]  list) {

        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

But there's one problem. In the question it prompts the user to enter list and the first element is length of that list. This means that we need to prompt the user only one time. So please explain how is this possible that first element becomes the size of an array??

Comment: Looking at your code `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` comes to my mind. (`list[i + 1]` with possible `i == list.length-1`)

Comment: Also, you are checking an `array` not `list`

Comment: So, the size of array is fixed. For eg if the user entered 8 10 1 5 16 61 9 11 1 then 8 would be its length. How to do this step in code??

Comment: If the user have entered 4 1 3 4 5 so 4 would be its length. How to write this in code?

Comment: Your `isSorted` method is wrong.  The loop will only execute once.  What if you have `1 2 3 5 4` ?  You need to get rid of the `else { return true; }`

Comment: Also you need to test whether `list[ i + 1]` is valid before calling it.  Probably by doing something like `if( i + 1 < list.length) { compare; }`

Comment: Thanks everyone for clarifying my queries.

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner class uses whitespace, any white space, as the delimiter between tokens by default. This means that if the user pressed return between entering numbers then you need to handle that case and ask the user for another number, or the end user would just be on a new line and not know what to do. If the user doesn't press return between entering the numbers but separates them with a space, for example:

1 2 3 4 5

then the scanner would separate that in to 5 separate tokens that would be returned one at once when you call nextInt().

If you run your program and enter something like:

4 2 1 3 4

It should out put four questions asking you to enter inout (that you have already given to it) but then perform the function you want anyway and print "The list is NOT sorted!".

PS. the program doesn't quite work as I imagine you want it to because you as it only checks if the first two values are in ascending order and then returns. Instead you should check to see if the first two are correct, set a flag to keep track of them if they are and then carry on with the loop without exiting. Or only return in the case where the list isn't sorted and if you get to the end of checking the array and you haven't exited it must be sorted and therefore you should return true (as in the code example below). The return statements force your method isSorted to exit as soon as it hits that line, without going through the whole loop. You should also check for going off the end of the array before trying to access i+1. Something like

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number.  for the length of the list: ");
        int listLength = input.nextInt();
        int[] number = new int[listLength];

        for(int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
            number[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        if (isSorted(number)) {
            System.out.println("The list is sorted!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The list is NOT sorted!");
        }

    }

    public static boolean isSorted(int[]  list) {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
            if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```